# Any one knows the tracking algorithm of facial feature of IntraFace of CMU?

Tags: face-detection, feature-detection, face-recognition

I am learning face feature detection algorithm now. I found the effect of [IntraFace](http://humansensing.cs.cmu.edu/intraface/index.php) is amazing?

I know the detection algorithm is SDM (supervised Descent method). But I have no idea which tracking algorithm it used?

Any one knows please tell me. Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tracking is SDM, detection is based on Viola&Jones face detection